# How can a researcher from a third-world country publish or otherwise disseminate an interesting result?

Tags: publications, research-process, independent-researcher, developing-countries

Given I am from a third world country,

Can you tell me please what to do if i get an interesting result or develop a promising theory .

Do you think that contacting a mathematics professor and asking to be admitted to a seminar in order to present the result is a good idea?

If yes, can you recommend me a region in the world where there are lots of chances of an affirmative answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "demanding to be admitted in a seminar." Do you mean that you want to visit universities in other countries and give a presentation about your work?

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't contact professors and "demand" anything, unless you are writing in French.  Also, your question doesn't have enough information: lots of academic mathematicians are "from a third world country". Many third world countries have universities, seminars, the works.  It seems to be implicit in your question that being from a third world country puts you at some obvious, specific disadvantage.  But it's not obvious to me what that is.  If you are the head of the math department at say UNAM, then you're in a much better position than an American without a degree.

Comment: Are you affiliated with a university or other research institution?

Comment: The first thing you should do is to write up your result as a paper and upload it to the arxiv.  That brings three benefits: (1) It establishes that you had the result at the time you uploaded it, even if publication takes much longer. (2) Many of the people who are interested in your topic subscribe to automatic notifications from the arxiv, so they'll get the abstract of your paper.  (3) In my experience, writing up a result is the best way to find any errors or gaps in my proofs.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that no one is going to invite you from overseas for a seminar unless they know you already. One of the best ways to disseminate your research is **conference participation**, but coming from a third-world country puts you at a disadvantage in terms of funding and travel possibilities. Sometimes conferences have **travel grants** for students and early career researchers (I don't know if you fit inside this category), which you can apply for. This can offset some of the costs (but not all, unfortunately). **Watch out for this kind of opportunities.**

Another thing that you should do is writing down your results in a **preprint** and trying to get it published. Once you have a preprint, you can **send it to a (small) number of researchers** working on the same area to try and get them interested. This could be a subset of the people you cite, for instance. Watch out for signs of **feedback** (positive and negative) from their part and don't overdo it -- you don't want to be considered a **spammer**.

Comment: Does mathematics use conferences in preference to journals? Publication in a journal would be logistically easier.

Comment: In mathematics, publication in journals is strongly preferred. Conference talks, though, are still an opportunity to present and advertise your journal paper to other researchers.